# Batch class is failing

Tags: apex, batch

when i am running my batch i am getting below error.

> First error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted
>   after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa):
>   Exception__c, original object: UserRole: []

can anyone please help what when wrong in my code.

Class Name: GenerateUserRoleHierarchy_Batch
    Purpose:    1. This class is used to insert all unique role in userRole form User_Role_Hierarchy__c custome object.

```
global class GenerateUserRoleHierarchy_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{

   global Map<String, String> mapRoleHierarchySrID = new Map<String, String>();

   global Map<String, String> mapRoleHierarchyName = new Map<String, String>();

   global Map<String,Id> userRoleMap = new Map<String,Id>();

   global String SoqlQuery;



/******************************************************************************
    Method Name     - GenerateUserRoleHierarchy_Batch
    Access Modifier - global
    Purpose         - This is constructor method queries all the User Role_Hierarchy data set required for populating parent child relationship in userRole object.
    Output          - List
    *******************************************************************************/

    global GenerateUserRoleHierarchy_Batch()
    {

   for(User_Role_Hierarchy__c roleHierarchyObj : [Select SR_ID__c, Manager_SR_ID__c, SR_Name__c From User_Role_Hierarchy__c])
        {

                    mapRoleHierarchySrID.put(roleHierarchyObj.SR_ID__c, roleHierarchyObj.Manager_SR_ID__c);

                    mapRoleHierarchyName.put(roleHierarchyObj.SR_ID__c, roleHierarchyObj.SR_Name__c);
        }

    List<UserRole> userRoleLst  = [Select Name,Id From UserRole order By Name];

    for(UserRole usrObj : userRoleLst)
    {
        userRoleMap.put(usrObj.Name, usrObj.Id);
    }

    SoqlQuery = 'Select Id, Name, parentRoleId From UserRole order By Name ';

    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        SoqlQuery = 'Select Id, Name, parentRoleId From UserRole order By Name Limit 200';
    }
}



global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator(SoqlQuery);
}



  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<UserRole> scope)
    {

        //Map<String,Id> userRoleMap = new Map<String,Id>();

        List<UserRole> userRoleLstToUpdate = new List<UserRole>();

        for(UserRole userRoleObj : scope)
        {
            if(userRoleObj.Name != Constants.exceptionRoleName)
            {
                List<String> roleSplit = new List<String>();
                String managerSrId = '';
                String managerSrName = '';
                String parentRole = '';
                //System.debug('###userRoleObj===>'+userRoleObj);
                if(userRoleObj.Name.contains('_Child'))
                {
                    parentRole = userRoleObj.Name.replace('_Child','');
                }
                else
                {
                    if(userRoleObj.Name.contains(Constants.strUnderScore))
                    {
                        roleSplit = userRoleObj.Name.split(Constants.strUnderScore);
                        if(roleSplit.size() > 1)
                        {
                            managerSrId = mapRoleHierarchySrID.get(roleSplit[1]);
                            managerSrName = mapRoleHierarchyName.get(managerSrId);
                        }

                        if(managerSrId != null && !String.isBlank(managerSrId))
                            parentRole = 'UPS_'+managerSrId+Constants.strUnderScore+managerSrName;
                    }
                }
                if(!String.isBlank(parentRole))
                {
                    if(userRoleMap.get(parentRole) == null && managerSrId != Constants.topMostRoleName )
                        userRoleObj.parentRoleId = userRoleMap.get(Constants.exceptionRoleName);
                    else
                        userRoleObj.parentRoleId = userRoleMap.get(parentRole);
                }
                userRoleLstToUpdate.add(userRoleObj);
            }
        }

        try
            {
                if(userRoleLstToUpdate.size() > 0)
                {
                    update userRoleLstToUpdate;
                }
            }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
              Batch_Util exceptionClass = new Batch_Util();
               insert exceptionClass.createException('GenerateUserRoleHierarchy_Batch','Batch Execute',e);
                system.debug('Error Message'+e.getMessage());
            } 

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

      AssignUserRole_Batch batchObj = new AssignUserRole_Batch(); 
      if(!Test.isRunningTest())
        {
            Database.executeBatch(batchObj);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Some sObjects Cannot Be Used Together in DML Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm):

> DML operations on certain sObjects, sometimes referred to as setup objects, can’t be mixed with DML on other sObjects in the same transaction. This restriction exists because some sObjects affect the user’s access to records in the org. You must insert or update these types of sObjects in a different transaction to prevent operations from happening with incorrect access-level permissions. For example, you can’t update an account and a user role in a single transaction. However, deleting a DML operation has no restrictions.

So by modifying `UserRole` you would be modifying users' access, in your case. The alternative to this is to do two separate transactions using `@future` annotated methods.

Comment: i cant use future method in batch class

Comment: can u please tell wt have to include in my code

Comment: You'll have to rework your logic for doing what you want to do, since you won't be able to use future methods on a batch class.